# Common child table to many master tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, database-design

I am using mysql database with php to build a web application .

I have a child table `attachment`, which is a common table for many master tables: `teacher`, `student`, `classRoom` (and others). 
The master tables number exceeds 10 lets say n tables.

My question's, is it a good practice to:

1. Create just one table in database called 'attachment' and relate it with its masters .
   This will cause to have n foreign keys in the attachment table (ie: n-1 unused columns ) which will leads too, to n-1 attributes in the model without being initialized or used each time I create a model .
2. Create a table for each master table (master_i) called (master_i_Attachment) and relate it just to its master. But this will lead to n attachments tables and n models for attachment in my code.

Any advice ?

Comment: What would be the use case of that table?

Comment: The attachment table is for storing the (name,filePath,fileType,fileSize,note, and other details...).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to just have a table with the following fields: id, reference_id (one of your parent tables), reference_type (ie to which table the reference_id belongs), (all the other fields in your attachment table).

Then, for example, if you want to get the attachments for the particular parent type, you can run SELECT query filtering on that type, e.g. WHERE reference_type='classroom'.

Or if you want to get the attachment for the classroom with a specific ID:

```
SELECT * FROM attachment WHERE reference_id=<ID> AND reference_type = 'classroom';
```

You will probably want to have a composite unique key on (reference_id, reference_type) which will ensure that you won't get duplicated attachments (unless you want the possibility for the given ID of the given type to have more than one attachment, in which case the key should not be unique).

Whether this solution suits your needs depends on how you are going to use the data, i.e. what kind of queries you are going to run most often.

Comment: Your solution is good ,but I think this will affect the integrity of the data.I need foreign key to relate the child with master. So I cannot delete a master record if it has children

Comment: You can do the same with the trigger, though indeed, you would have to set up the triggers for all the parent tables. In that case your option 2 is probably the best choice.

Comment: If I adopted choice #2. Lets transfer the problem to the code, what about the code ? 
I am thinking to make one model that manage all the attachment tables in database with a type attribute in the model class to differentiate them. Is it a good practice ?

Comment: It looks like a reasonable solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [database normalization concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), using redundant and uninitialized (or null) values in database is discouraged. Actually normalization tries to isolate data more and more (it means more table for any anomaly). **BUT** you can simply ignore rules or denormalize your database for performance issues.

In your case, I think the simplest (and normalized) way would be choice number #2 (a separate table for each attachment type). But you can tweak your design as Ashalynd says. Put a `type` column in your table to specify the parent table. BTW using this method will add complexity for cascading changes in database.

Comment: If I adopted choice #2. Lets transfer the problem to the code, what about the code ? I am thinking to make one model that manage all the attachment tables in database with a type attribute in the model class to differentiate them. Is it a good practice ?

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem in a non-changing program. But if you want to look at it as a software engineering question, I think the right way is to use object orientation concepts in your code. For example an abstract class for managing attachments which can be specialized for each attachment type (although this is more complex, it will be easily changeable and expandable in the future).